# C# create a synonymous type for System.Single with a subset of features

Tags: c#, .net, struct, initialization, base-class-library

I want to create a type that is basically equivalent to `System.Single`, but with a subset of features. The reason for this is I have algorithms that emit timestamps in `System.Single` and I want to add extension methods to work with the results.

It would be inappropriate to add `Method(this float a)` as invalid values could be passed in.

I looked at the `System.Single` source code [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/single.cs,dda909df0f8d2fd0). However, I don't understand why there's no constructor or setter of any sort. I checked a few of the other base value types and none of them have any visible method of setting the value.

How is this possible?

The reason I ask is I want my new type to be operable in the same way as the base types, so I want to create a type with the same behavior.

Comment: System.Single being a "value type" *is* a value. Usually and for good reasons value types don't have setters; see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil

Comment: Alright, but how do I create one? Defining a struct with no setter doesn't enable one to state `MyStruct x = 3`. The compiler has no idea what to set.

Comment: If there is an implicit conversion operator like `public static explicit operator MyStruct(float f) => new MyStruct { _value = f };`, your code should work.

Comment: @KlausGütter Though your code shows an explicit conversion operator, not an implicit one.

Comment: I made it `implicit` and it works fine. I don't understand how the .Net source code works without one, though.

Comment: @ckuri Right you are - thanks for correcting

Comment: @IamIC Support for basic types is baked into the language